# Convert Ant build script into Maven build

Tags: java, maven, ant

This is the Ant one target which i want to convert in Pom.xml. My problem
is how to write these steps in POM. My Project structure are not
standard also.

```
   My project structure is like com.ABD/Src/com/sp/gateway/Abc.java 
   file.

          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <echo message=">>>>>>>>>compile" />
                    <mkdir dir="bin" />
                    <javac srcdir="com.sc.lms.gateway/src" 
                       destdir="bin"
                        classpathref="classpath" source="8" target="8" 
                       />

                      <copy todir="bin">
                        <fileset dir="WebContent">
                            <include name="**/*.xml" />
                        </fileset>
                    </copy>
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: As already mentioned. You have to create pom.xml file define your dependencies etc. and Maven is not a scripting langauge.

Comment: yes i know Maven is not scription language.. i m writing plugins in POm.xml also...but creating directory setting classpath is getting difficult for me syntex wise.

Comment: Please show what you exactly are doing. What does this: `but creating directory setting classpath is getting difficult for me syntex wise` means?

Comment: The classpath in Maven is automatically created from the dependencies. You don't use lib folders.

Comment: I have added my exact issue...i want to compile some java classes ( Project structure is not standard )and put it on bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You don't.

Maven is not a scripting language like Ant. It has lifecycle and you bind plugins to the lifecycle. These plugins do the work.

Comment: Hello J fabian i have updated my question...will u able to answer it.

Comment: Why not use the standard Maven project structure?

Comment: In Maven you use the standard project structure of Maven. You can change things, but you really shouldn't do it.

Comment: But now i cant change the structure..this is already a big project which is running from so long time. Can we do anything here with these directory structure.

Comment: You probably can, I don't know, I never change the standard directory layout. But now you are moving from Ant to Maven. This is the right time to refactor the project structure. Why not just move the source code to `src/main/java` and then compile to `target` as everyone else?